# Full list of LinkedIn endorsements

Tags: data-request, business

Do LinkedIn share their full list of endorsements? Is there a similar dataset of work skills, technologies, abilities and interests?

Comment: Do you mean all possible endorsements, or endorsements for a certain person? Either way, Endorsements and Skills are not available as part of the API: http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/skill-endorsements and web scraping is against the Terms of Service.

Comment: all possible endorsements

Comment: Users can create custom endorsements so the list is infinite.

Comment: There's a finite list of endorsements that are currently being used. This is what I'm after.

Comment: I just made a skill based on knowing the alphabet and anyone is free to endorse me: http://imgur.com/vfHYjQL

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that is available right now on Linkedin is the skills from a certain user and not the endorsements. And in order to download the skills, users have to log in with auth. Unfortunately, you will not find any **complete** list of skills from Linkedin.

If you want to download the skills from a certain user, here is the code for python using this [library](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin).

```
from linkedin import linkedin

API_KEY = '.............'     # This is api_key
API_SECRET = '...........'   # This is secret_key

RETURN_URL = '.............'

authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())

authentication.authorization_code = code

authentication.get_access_token()

application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)

skills = application.get_profile(selectors=['skills'])
```